# Django: escaping translations with safe

Tags: html, django

I've got a problem. When I use HTML Tags in a translation (.po files) they end up being displayed as: &lt;p&gt;. When I use the |safe filter it results in <p>. But I don't get it to work that the actual html tags are passed.

Anyone got a clue about this?

```
.po file:
#: website/views.py:35
msgid "web_content_detailed"
msgstr "<h1>asdjkasjdlas</h1>"

view.py:
context = {}
context['somevar'] = _('web_content_detailed')
return render(request, 'somehtml.html', context)

somehtml.html:
{{ somevar }} => &lt;h1&gt;asdjkasjdlas&lt;/h1&gt;
{{ somevar|safe }} => <h1>asdjkasjdlas</h1>`
```

Comment: can you post some code ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zWzJhnSJ

Comment: Try in your template: `{% trans somevar %}`

Comment: Its not about the translation not working. The translations are working perfectly. The problem is, that the format specified in the .po file is not applied. Just shown as plaintext.